# Android Studio unlimited search results

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

It seems that Android Studio limits search results by 100 in "Find in path" view. I need to find all the occurrences. Is there an option to disable the limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Open in Find Window** button to get all the results.

Comment: Appreciated. Nice answer.